# Using Python scripts with external modules on other computers?

Tags: python

Suppose I need to distribute a python script to other computers but I'm using modules downloaded from remote sources that need to be installed locally. Is there a standard way of doing that?

Comment: Keywords: [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), [Nuitka](http://nuitka.net/pages/overview.html). Depending on what you are doing one of them (most likely pip) will answer your question.

Comment: for elements installed by `pip` you need only `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Comment: Also look at conda. Much easier than pip.

Answer (score 1):

The official packaging tutorial for Python tells how to create redistributable Python packages: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing/

Specifically, the `setup.py` in your package can define dependencies to to third party libraries: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing/#install-requires